# .to_csv produces csv file which contains random date format

Tags: python, date, pandas, format, dataframe

While using `.to_csv method to convert Dataframes`. I get random date format for the date strings.

For a given column in csv, date format weirdly fluctuates between mm/dd/yy and mm-dd-yyyy. The original dataframe does not have this problem.

Sample column in **.csv file**

```
03-01-2014

10/19/13

04-11-2014

09/19/14

09/19/14

12/18/13

03-10-2013

04/13/14
```

I used the below code to generate the date column

```
def Get_random_date():
    t=datetime.datetime.now()
    mon=t.month
    dy=t.day
    yr=t.year

    year = random.choice(range(2013, yr+1))
    month = random.choice(range(1, mon+1))
    day = random.choice(range(1, 28))

    return pd.datetime(year,month,day)

def Generate_Dates():   
  DateCreated = pd.Series([])

  date_created=Get_random_date()

  DateCreated=date_created.strftime('%x')

  return (DateCreated)     
  ... 
  row=pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=dt.columns)
  row['Date Created']=Generate_Dates()
  ...
  new_dt.to_csv('new_data.csv')
```

Sample column in **.csv file**

```
03-01-2014

10/19/13

04-11-2014

09/19/14

09/19/14

12/18/13

03-10-2013

04/13/14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could do:

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Similar to @bcollins but notice the `/` between each string identifier.

Or you could use Pandas [to_datetime(args)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) functionality like so:

```
dates = [ "03-01-2014",
         "10/19/13",
         "04-11-2014",    
         "09/19/14",    
         "09/19/14",    
         "12/18/13",   
         "03-10-2013",   
         "04/13/14" ]

df = pd.DataFrame(dates)
df = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
```

Obviously you would replace the `0` with the name of the column that your dates are under within your data frame, but I'm sure you get the idea.

This results in:

```
0   2014-03-01
1   2013-10-19
2   2014-04-11
3   2014-09-19
4   2014-09-19
5   2013-12-18
6   2013-03-10
7   2014-04-13
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can then write this to the `csv` file you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying a date_format?

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: I added it but it doesn't change the output.